# Commit history mess after squashing into master

Tags: git, merge, squash

I have two branches in a repo: `master` and `dev`.

State of `dev` is

```
- A - S1 - S2 - ... - SN - B - C
```

State of `master` is

```
- A - S
```

Where `S` commit is the result of "squash and merge" of `S1`, ..., `SN` from `dev` to `master`.

Now, when I compare the branches, git shows a lot of changes, but actually they are `B` and `C`.

1. What the best way to sync the branches?
2. What the proper workflow to avoid such situations?

Comment: how are you running diff? `git diff dev..master`? `git diff dev...master`? Can you include that in the question?

Comment: About the general questions: **unless you know what you are doing**, squashing and merging won't fly if you mean to have some relation between the branches because git is _not_ able to see how the branches are related past `A` (because you are not creating common history between them). To git, S is just a revision on top of A that has **no relationship whatsoever with S1..SN**.

Comment: I faced the problem trying to merge `dev` into `main`. I [compare](https://github.com/vvpisarev/CubicEoS.jl/compare/dev) the branches as `main...dev` on github. The real changes in `dev` (labeled as `B - C` in questions) are [commits](https://github.com/vvpisarev/CubicEoS.jl/commits/dev) since 17 February (six last commits in `dev`).

Comment: @eftshift0, I can find commits (`B` and `C`) that are actually changes on top of `S`. Is it possible to "detach" `-B-C` chain and merge into `main` only this chain?

Comment: You could cherry-pick B and C onto `main`, but if `dev` is a long-living branch, it's best to do a normal merge. Squash merges are useful for short-lived branches that you delete after the merging, not for long-living ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.... your comments explain what's going on. So, github will use triple dots when doing a diff. So, if you tried `git diff master..dev`, you would only see what B and C introduced. But github will use `master...dev` (or viceversa, does not matter). Try with git with triple dot and you will see that it will also include the changes introduces by S, and that is because when you do `master...dev`, git *won't* just compare master and dev. It will first find the last common ancestor between them (`A`) and then `git diff A..dev`, which will include the changes introduced by `S1..SN`... same thing if you tried `dev...master`. It would end up doing `git diff A..master` (which would include changes from `S`). And that is because when you squashed/merge, there was no real merge.

The way to kind of get this working again would be to set `dev` to have `B` and `C` on top of **current** master:

```
git rebase --onto master SN dev
```

That should get you what you want, but you lose the history of `S1~..SN`. Another way would be to get this properly merged..... but hacking a little bit so that you won't have to redo yourself (say, did you have to solve conflicts and stuff? I don't know.... so), you could try this:

```
git commit-tree -p A -p SN -m "Merging S" S^{tree}
# this will create a new _merge_ revision having A and SN as parents
# the content of the files will be the same as S
# the command will print the ID of a revision
# take that revision ID and let's call it X
# branch dev can live on the way it is.... we just need to put master where X is
git checkout master # if you are not in master already
# make sure you have no changes uncommitted as the next command will destroy those changes
git reset --hard X 
# now master is on top of X, the way it should have been
```

Now, do **not** ever try squashing/merging ever again *unless you know what you are doing*.

Comment: Thank you for productive answer and discussion!

Comment: After some testing, I came up with this solution, but I notice, that my repository is small and maintaining mostly by me. So. Locally, I made a branch `dev_local` from `dev` and rebased local branch as `git rebase -r --onto master SN dev_local` ([`-r` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786404/merge-commits-dont-appear-in-git-rebase-interactive)). Then I created a remote branch `dev_new` from `master` and merged locally `dev_local` into `dev_new`. After that, I removed `dev` in repo and renamed `dev_new` to `dev`.